# Podio API reattach file to another item

Tags: php, podio

I am using the podio API and have Items with Files attached to them in one app - for internal reasons, we want to split up these items and move some of the data to items in another app. Now I have the problem, that I cannot attach Files from one Item in one app to another Item in another app.

If I authenticate the "old" app, then it doesnt have the permission to attach a File to the Item in the "new" app.

```
$oldApp->attachFile('old_file_id', array('ref_type' => 'item', 'ref_id' => 'new_item_id'));
```

If I authenticate the "new" app, it doenst have the permission to edit the file in the "old" app - so far i have not found a way to move the files.

```
$newApp->attachFile('old_file_id', array('ref_type' => 'item', 'ref_id' => 'new_item_id'));
```

I tried the normal attach function and also a copy -> attach approach, but neither work.

```
$copiedFile=$oldApp->copyFile('old_file_id');
$newApp->attachFile($copiedFile->file_id, array('ref_type' => 'item', 'ref_id' => 'new_item_id'));
```

This also produces the error that the new Item does not have permission to edit the copied file.

```
Status: 403 Message: The app with id'new_app_id' does not have the right update on file with id 'file_id'
```

If anyone has a suggestion, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Utilizing Podio facilitates the seamless execution of this task. By creating a reference to a new app within the existing one, you establish a linkage between them. Subsequently, within the original app, configuring a workflow ensures that whenever an update occurs, the corresponding file is automatically relocated to the designated "collected" item.

[Podio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6bKY.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).